# Align and proprerly format a Rcase inside of tabular

Tags: latex

I am a beginner at latex, and I am having a hard time properly using the align command and properly format a Rcase inside of tabular. My problems are the bracket of the rcase is clipping the border of the box, and the Rcase is not properly align vertical with with the other function, I have try using the align command, but don't know how to format it, when there is another column, that has to be excluded before it.

Here's what is produced

[image]

I am very lost here, so if any one could help or point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\arctanh}{tanh^{-1}}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\arcsech}{sech^{-1}}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\arccsch}{csch^{-1}}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\arccoth}{coth^{-1}} 

    \begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{4\linewidth}
      \begin{tabular}{|l r | l r|}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\normalfont \textbf{Hyperbolic}} & 
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\normalfont \textbf{Inverse Hyperbolic}} \\        
            \midrule
            \itshape Defintions: & \itshape {$\frac{Odd}{Even}$:} 
                                                           & \itshape Defintions: & \itshape Domain:\\
             $ \sech x  = \frac {1} {\cosh x} 
             = \frac {2} {e^x + e^{-1}} 
             = \frac {2e^{x}}{e^{2x} + 1}$
             & {Even}                                      & $\arcsech x    = \ln( \frac {1}{x} + \sqrt{\frac{1}
                                                                                                 {x^2} - 1 } \,) 
                                                                         = \ln ( \frac {1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x}),$
                                                                                 &(  0, 1  \big]            \\
            $ \tanh x  = \frac {\sinh x}{\cosh x} 
            = \frac {e^x - e^{-1}}{e^x + e^{-1}} 
            = \frac {e^{2x} - 1}{e^{2x} + 1} $
            & {Odd}       
                                            & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}{*}{
                                                $\begin{rcases} 
                                                      \arctanh x,  & \text{For } (-1, 1) \\
                                                      \arccoth x,  & \text{For } (-\infty, -1) \, U \, (1 , \infty)
                                                \end{rcases}$ 
                                                                = $\frac {1}{2} \ln ( \frac {1+x}{1-x})$}}                                                                              &                             \\
            $ \coth x  = \frac {\cosh x}{\sinh x} 
            = \frac {e^x + e^{-1}}{e^x - e^{-1}} 
            = \frac {e^{2x} + 1}{e^{2x} - 1}$
            & {Odd}                         &  & \\
            \bottomrule
          \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}\hfill



    \end{equation*}  

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: to avoid the bracket going over the bottom rule of your table, you could add some additional space with `\addlinespace`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctanh}{tanh^{-1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsech}{sech^{-1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccsch}{csch^{-1}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccoth}{coth^{-1}} 

\begin{document}

%\begin{minipage}[t]{4\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l r | l r|}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\normalfont \textbf{Hyperbolic}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\normalfont \textbf{Inverse Hyperbolic}} \\        
\midrule
\itshape Defintions: & \itshape {$\frac{\text{Odd}}{\text{Even}}$:} 
& \itshape Defintions: & \itshape Domain:\\
$ \sech x  = \frac {1} {\cosh x} 
= \frac {2} {e^x + e^{-1}} 
= \frac {2e^{x}}{e^{2x} + 1}$
& {Even}                                      & $\arcsech x    = \ln( \frac {1}{x} + \sqrt{\frac{1}
{x^2} - 1 } \,) 
= \ln ( \frac {1 + \sqrt{1 - x^2}}{x}),$
&(  0, 1  \big]            \\
$ \tanh x  = \frac {\sinh x}{\cosh x} 
= \frac {e^x - e^{-1}}{e^x + e^{-1}} 
= \frac {e^{2x} - 1}{e^{2x} + 1} $
& {Odd}       
& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}{*}{
$\begin{rcases} 
\arctanh x,  & \text{For } (-1, 1) \\
\arccoth x,  & \text{For } (-\infty, -1) \, U \, (1 , \infty)
\end{rcases}$ 
= $\frac {1}{2} \ln ( \frac {1+x}{1-x})$}}                                                                              &                             \\
$ \coth x  = \frac {\cosh x}{\sinh x} 
= \frac {e^x + e^{-1}}{e^x - e^{-1}} 
= \frac {e^{2x} + 1}{e^{2x} - 1}$
& {Odd}                         &  & \\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}



\end{document}
```

[image]

(it is not recommended to use vertical rules together with the `booktabs` package -- removing the vertical lines would also get rid of the gaps between the lines...)